# How to insert tabledata into table with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working in a project with vue-cli and they want me to generate a listlike view (pun intended) onto data from the database.

I've never really worked with vue. 4 months ago I was given some time to find my way into it, but then I had to work on our lumen-driven backend api and so I forgot most of the stuff. And besides that, I really find vue utterly confusing.

So I need to do this step by step since I dont have loads of time at hand to throughly learn the framework before actually producing usable results.

I have the following template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>myList</h1>
    <table id="testTable"></table>
    <button class="button" v-on:click='fetchList'>myButton</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import store from "../store/store";

import { USER_FETCHLIST } from "../store/actions/user";

export default {

  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchList: function(){
      var test = store.dispatch(USER_FETCHLIST).then((res)=> {
        console.log(res)
        document.getElementById("testTable").InnerHTML = res
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The fetchList() successfully fetches the data from the DB. But I cant insert anything into my table element, at least not this "javascript-way" which I tried in the above code. 
For example, when I try to input this string:  `<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>` into the table element, nothing happens.

I learnt about v-bind and all this stuff, but I really don't know how to implement it here.

I *also* must emphasize that I absolutely want to avoid building this component from subcomponents. 
The "inheritance" in vue.js is pretty different from the usual inheritance in programming and I really tried to get my head around it, but I just cant make anything useful with it in my relatively short timeframe. 
So I need to have all the JS and html in place in this component.

Can anyone give me a hand in propery binding the prefabricated HTML-String to the table element?
Thank you!

Comment: there's `v-html`

Comment: The `<template>` tag holds its content hidden from the client.

Content inside a `<template>` tag will not be rendered.

The content can be made visible and rendered later by using JavaScript.